# IBM Worklight- HTTP adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How to create an HTTP adapter to retrieve the file on a web host.
I'm confuse because HTTP adapter is used to retrieve json output used for RSS feed. How can i target for files (e.g .jpg).

thanks.

Comment: The jpg path should be inside the response coming back in json output then you can grab the file.

Comment: @Hussam Eddin how to grab the file then?

Comment: Idan's Answer explains exactly how to grab it. I'm following the same steps to get it in my project.

Comment: how to use apache cordova in worklight?

Comment: See my Answer, please note we are not required to teach you how to code. you need to try and we can fix for you and assist you.

Comment: can i have a very good source where i can learn ibm worklight?

Comment: http://www-03.ibm.com/certify/tests/eduC2180-408.shtml (Open the URL and click on test preparation and see the materials. Also IBM knowledge centre is a great source.

Comment: If my answer is sufficient for you, please mark as "answered".

Comment: where should i place the custom Java code, is it to the server where the .gif is found?

Comment: No, it is under your worklight project inside eclipse. See my updated answer.

Comment: {i'm having this error:
      "Ecma Error: TypeError: Cannot call property getImage in object [JavaPackage com.company.ProjectName.ImageEncoder]. It is not a function, it is \"object\". (TransferAdap-impl.js#42)"

Comment: YOU NEED TO LEARN HOW TO RUN THE JAVA CODE ON THE SERVER. Highlight your project > Click on Project Manu in your eclipse top bar > Build Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions provided [in this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mobileblog/entry/ibm_worklight_adapter_accessing_an_image?lang=en).

The steps are as follows:

1. Provide the remote image URL as a parameter to the adapter
2. Base64 encode the returned image on the server using a Java utility
3. Return the encoded base64 string to the application
4. Base64 decode the string and display the image